# How can install alternate version of Boost C++ library on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, boost, homebrew

I am trying to install Boost C++ using Homebrew in Mac.
$brew install boost .
This installs latest version 1.75 ,
I want to install lower versions like 1.70 . Is there a way I can maintain alternate versions ?
I am open to any pkg manager other than brew . If there is any please suggest .

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

homebrew also hosts `boost@1.57` and `boost@1.60` (`brew search boost`). If the version you need is not one of those, you could always install it yourself; it's not like you have to maintain an older installation. You just have to go through the "hassle" of following the installation instructions.

Comment: Hi Sweenish , thanks for your answer . So versioned installation is no more supported by brew . i.e " boost install boost@1.57" something like this is not supported , I already  tried that .  Also I know that we can build boost manually and have our own custom installation . My question was , can we do that using brew or not . I also reached to a point when I was able to create a Formula (.rb script) that brew uses to install . But was not able to make it through . So I want to know did any one tried to do using brew or any pkg management .